# Can we find the value of a particular fitting parameter from Quadratic equation?

Tags: matplotlib, curve-fitting

In the following code I want to find the value of fitting parameter v. I know that power-law relation should hold for my data points. But I get best fit to my data points when I fit a quadratic equation. But in quadratic equation what will be v? If I fit power-law then error is large so what should I do in such a situation?  [image: Fitting Quadratic equation]
[image: Fitting a power law]

```
`import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import scipy 
from scipy import optimize

fig = plt.figure()
ax= fig.add_subplot(111)

x_data = np.array([21,42,63,84]) 
y_data= np.array([0.14829848, 0.08196068, 0.04347054, 0.03137703])

def power_law(L,v):
    return (L**(-1/v))

def ff(L,a,b,Ec):
    return (a*(L)**2 + b*L +Ec) 

ax2.scatter(x_data, y_data, marker='s',s=4**2,)


pfit,pcov = optimize.curve_fit(ff,x_data,y_data)
print("pfit: ",pfit)
print("pcov: ",pcov.shape)
#print(pcov)
perr = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))
x=np.linspace(20,85,1000)

ax2.plot(x,ff(x,*pfit),color='red')`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quadratic equation in your code has an offset term. The power law equation also needs an offset term. Here is a graphical Python fitter using your data and the power law from your code plus an offset.

[image: plot]

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


xData = numpy.array([21,42,63,84], dtype=float) 
yData= numpy.array([0.14829848, 0.08196068, 0.04347054, 0.03137703])


def func(L, v, offset):
    return (L**(-1.0/v)) + offset


# these are the same as the scipy defaults
initialParameters = numpy.array([1.0, 1.0])

# curve fit the test data
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, initialParameters)

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 

absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))

print('Parameters:', fittedParameters)
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = func(xModel, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```

Comment: But I have some confusion. If I use power law as (a*L^(-1/v)+c) I get v=2.15 with an error of 1.57, But if I use formula that you mentioned for power law I get quite accurate value of v. Why is it so? Is that indicates that my data points are less for 3 fitting parameters? How to decide which function should I prefer?

Comment: The offset parameter in both the quadratic and in my function act to directly shift the curve up and down vertically on the y axis. for example, if the data were generated by "power law + 50" then the fitted offset parameter should be 50, and without that parameter a power law *by itself* would not fit the data. Your data has a small offset included, so the equation used to model your data should include an offset parameter to account for that. I know that electronic amplifiers and sensors can introduce such an offset into measurements.

Comment: There is one more parameters a in that equation. If I introduce that then error of my fitting parameters is large. What can be the reason for that? Does skipping a means that my fitting function is incorrect?

Comment: The function " (a*L^(-1/v)+c)" has a gain factor "a" that will affect the fitted value of v, and has parameter "c" as an offset. When I use this function in the code I posted the fit seems good. I did have to add one more initial parameter value as this array contains one value for each fitted parameter, but I made no other change when using the new function.